# Elasticsearch not returning from index

Tags: elasticsearch

I am querying my index:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
   "match_phrase" : {
     "keywords" : "Apprenticeship"
    }
  }
}
```

I can see in my index that the record is within the index (it returns for other phrases) AND `Apprenticeship` is within keywords. Also it does return for `plasterer`.

Other records from within the index are returning but not this one and I can't work out why.

```
{
  "_source": {
    "id": "1806",
    "keywords": [
      "site manager",
      "construction worker",
      "joiner",
      "carpenter",
      "shop fitter",
      "builder",
      "construction projects",
      "plasterer",
      "decorator",
      "painter",
      "apprentice",
      "apprenticeship",
      "Apprenticeship",
      "Adv Apprenticeship"
    ]
  }
}
```

there are other fields such as body, title etc.

mapping:

```
{
  "coursedir" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "courses" : {
        "properties" : {
          "id" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "interestKeywords" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "keywords" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "moduleentry" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "modulefaculty" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "moduleid" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "moduleintro" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "moduleprogression" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "modulereference" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "modulesite" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "url_title" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`coursedir` settings:

```
{
  "coursedir" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1420800223281",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "uuid" : "yXzkAI_2Tx-CGKfkMusZmw",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "1040299"
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the mapping for that index.

Comment: mapping added to question

Comment: If you search for `apprenticeship` does it return something?

Comment: not the record in question, however it does return other records

Comment: Post the output of `GET /coursedir/_settings`.

Comment: In my opinion it should return that document, not sure why it doesn't.